# R: gsub remove \

Tags: r, character

I've worked with `gsub` to remove `+`, here's my code:

```
clean_up[,5] <- gsub("\\+", "",clean_up[,5])
```

But now I want to remove the character `\`. How can I do this with `gsub`?

Comment: what is `clean_up`?  A reproducible example would be helpful here.

Comment: That's the name of my matrix. So I would like to remove \ out of my fifth column of clean_up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
a <- "This is a \\string."
gsub("\\p{P}", "", a, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "This is a string"
```

Answer (score -1):

The backslash is a special character, and it too must be escaped:

```
clean_up[,5] <- gsub("\\\", "",clean_up[,5])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need four backslashes